# C# Appending list to excel file

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

so currently my code below generates a string and adds it to a list for each image file in a directory, then after its does adding to the list, it opens an excel file, appends the list, and formats it. Currently my problem is that my excel line is selecting the entireColumn and pasting the list, how can I get it to recognize how many strings are in the list and only append that many to the excel sheet.

```
        //Fill A2:B6 with an array of values .
        oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2");
        oRng.EntireColumn.Value2 = checkInformation.ToArray();
```

Here is my whole project

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
        object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("Initializing Check Parser Menu.....");
        string dataPath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tesseract\Tesseract\tessdata";
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tesseract\Tesseract\Check_Images", "*.png");
        string checkData = "";
        int checkCounter = 0;
        List<string> checkInformation = new List<string>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            checkCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing Check Parser... on Check: " + checkCounter);
            using (TesseractEngine ocr = new TesseractEngine(dataPath, "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
            {
                using (Pix p = Pix.LoadFromFile(filePath))
                {
                    using (Pix img = p.Scale(2, 3))
                    {

                        using (var page = ocr.Process(img))
                        {

                            string text = page.GetText();

                            if (text.Contains("Claim ID"))
                            {
                                int indexOfNone = text.IndexOf("NONE");
                                int indexOfClaimId = text.IndexOf("Claim ID");
                                int difference = indexOfClaimId - indexOfNone;
                                var dollarData = text.Substring(indexOfNone, difference);
                                int startingPoint = indexOfNone + (dollarData.Length - 6);
                                var dollarAmount = text.Substring(startingPoint, 6);
                                var claimIdData = text.Substring(indexOfClaimId, 14);
                                var claimInfoOutput = claimIdData + " Check Amount: " + dollarAmount;

                                Console.WriteLine(claimInfoOutput);
                                checkInformation.Add(claimInfoOutput);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You will need to locate this check, there was an issue parsing " + "\n" + filePath);
                                Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to continue");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        Console.WriteLine("Writing Data to Excel File... DONT TaCH");
        try
        {
            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;

            //Get a new workbook.
            oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            //Add table headers going cell by cell. //Format A1:B1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Claim ID";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Check Amount";
            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

            // Create an array to multiple values at once.

            //Fill A2:B6 with an array of values .
            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2");
            oRng.Value2 = checkInformation.ToArray();
            //oSheet.get_Range("A2", "B6").Value2 = checkInformation.ToArray();


            //Fill A2 with a formula(=MID(C2,9,5) 
            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A2", "A50");
            oRng.Formula = "=MID(C2,9,5)";
            //Fill B2 with a =RIGHT(C2,6)
            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("B2", "B50");
            oRng.Formula = "=RIGHT(C2,6)";

            //AutoFit columns A:C.
            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1");
            oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.UserControl = false;
            oWB.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Tesseract\\Tesseract\\excel\\checkdata.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            oWB.Close();
            ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2");
                oRng.Value2 = checkInformation.ToArray();

Comment: I changed it to the above, and I only get one instance of the list. I copied and pasted my image file 3 times and it went through the process 3 times, but when it came to appending the list to "C2" i only get 1 line of the list.

Comment: if I remove the checkInformation.ToArray(); and change it to simply checkInformation, It doesnt do anything and quits the code at that line with no furthur editing.

Comment: I even added phony data to the list that would replicate different checks, and I changed the range to C2, C10 and it just fills all the cells with the first object in the list

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it guys sorry to bug you but heres what I did.

```
            //Fill A2:B6 with an array of values .
            string cellName;
            int counter = 2;
            foreach (var check in checkInformation)
            {
                cellName = "C" + counter.ToString();
                oRng = oSheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
                oRng.Value2 = check.ToString();
                ++counter;
            }
```

and basically i just need to say for each item in my list this is the first cell name append the value.tostring